# WebWorker failing in compressed ES6 module

Tags: javascript, webpack, imagefilter

- I'm using a library (Image Filter) which utilizes WebWorkers
- Works fine until compressed (with Webpack / UglifyJsPlugin)
- `module.exports = function (self) {}` possibly the crux of the issue
- Issue occurring with [image-filter-core](https://github.com/canastro/image-filter-core). Bug raised here: https://github.com/canastro/image-filter-core/issues/6

---

**console error**

`blob:https://[path-to-worker] Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`

---

The `e` it is referencing is `self` in worker.js:

**SRC**

```
module.exports = function (self) {
    self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        importScripts(e.data.transformationURL);

        var canvasData = e.data.canvasData;

        var length = e.data.length;
        var index = e.data.index;

        transform(canvasData.data, length, e.data.options);

        self.postMessage({
            result: canvasData,
            index: index
        });

        self.close();
    });
};
```

**COMPRESSED**

```
e.addEventListener("message", function(t) {
  importScripts(t.data.transformationURL);
  var n = t.data.canvasData,
    r = t.data.length,
    o = t.data.index;
  transform(n.data, r, t.data.options), e.postMessage({
    result: n,
    index: o
  }), e.close()
})
```